# sed replacement \1 not working

Tags: sed, ubuntu-12.04

Typing the following on the command line:

```
    echo happy | sed -r s/\([p]\)\([p]\)/*\1*\2*/
```

I expect the following result:

```
    ha*p*p*y
```

Instead, this is the result:

```
    ha*1*2*y
```

I am using  Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-53-generic x86_64)
The shell is -ksh
sed is 4.2.1 December 2010

The -r option allowed me to use `\(` and `\)`.  I thought it would also enable `\1` and `\2` but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Is there another option I'm overlooking?

Comment: The `-r` switch obviates the need for `\\`'s on `(){}+?|` metacharacters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When typed on the command line, the shell is interpreting some of your backslash characters, so `sed` never sees them.

Instead, try one of these.  Notice the single quotes which preserves the literal backslash characters.

```
echo happy | sed -r 's/([p])([p])/*\1*\2*/'
```

or

```
echo happy | sed 's/\([p]\)\([p]\)/*\1*\2*/'
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `-r` just use

```
echo happy | sed  's/\(p\)\([p]\)/*\1*\2*/'
```